# Attempting to change shell to ZSH on Amazon Linux: Asking for ec2-user's password

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, shell, amazon-ami

[image]

What do I enter? I use the provided private-key to authenticate when SSH-ing to the server, so I don't think I actually have a password for the user...

Also tried this:

[image]

Comment: "shell not changed" because you changed to `/bin/bash` :)

Answer (score 1):

Had to do that last one from `bash`:

[image]

Comment: actually on your question you attempted to switch from/to `/bin/bash` and on your answer you correctly attempted to switch from `/bin/bash` to `/bin/zsh`